# Finding out how when google last crawled

Tags: unix, scripting, logging, googlebot

I'd like to find out how current google's cached copy of a large set of pages is.  I think I need to

1. look in the logs for IP's,
2. check to find user-agent "googlebot", then
3. export a list that says each page and when it was last visited.

I imagine this could be a cron job that runs weekly.  If this is right, how would I write the script?  If this is wrong, what would be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google already provides this information via [Google SiteMaps](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2F&hl=en). I have used it for the past three years - works great.

Add your site to SiteMaps and put a generated SiteMap XML of your site (Google for websites that provide this free) on your web server, then let Google do the rest. There is section in SiteMaps called *Crawl Stats* that gives you what you want.

> **Get Google's view of your site and diagnose problems**
>
> See how Google crawls and indexes your
>   site and learn about specific problems
>   we're having accessing it.
>
> **Discover your link and query traffic**
>
> View, classify, and download
>   comprehensive data about internal and
>   external links to your site with new
>   link reporting tools. Find out which
>   Google search queries drive traffic to
>   your site, and see exactly how users
>   arrive there.
>
> **Share information about your site**
>
> Tell us about your pages with
>   Sitemaps: which ones are the most
>   important to you and how often they
>   change. You can also let us know how
>   you would like the URLs we index to
>   appear.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't necessary, you can do a service call to Google to look up the cached page, i.e. searching for [cache:stackoverflow.com](http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), which included the time and date. I wouldn't be surprised if there's an api call to do this more directly (update: [Google Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/)).

Answer (score 0):

Last Googlebot Access can also be found for free via some websites like mypagerank.net or the Google Toolbar.